# Get network path of mounted drive, windows

Tags: python, windows, pywin32

The question is: how i can resolve mounted network drive letter to it's network path in Windows using python?

Does pywin32 or any other python's module can do it?

I've played around pywin32file and it's methods, but i didn't figure out how to do it.

All examples and help will be very appreciated!

Comment: The win32 api to achieve this is `WNetGetConnection` which seems to be recently supported `win32wnet.WNetGetConnection`

Comment: @AlexK.yep, description says if my drive is H: and there's a file 1.txt on drive, i have to use this method like:
`win32wnet.WNetGetConnection("H:\\1.txt")`
but i get an error
pywintypes.error: 
`(1200, 'WNetGetConnection', 'The specified device name is invalid.')`

Comment: It wants just the drive so you need to pass it "H:" (or possibly "H:\")

Comment: @AlexK.In this case ("H:") it falls with error:
`pywintypes.error: (2250, 'WNetGetConnection', 'This network connection does not exist.')`